# Data file 'main.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'utf8': Wide character at C:\Users\...\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 163

Tags: biblatex, texstudio, biber, mendeley

I am trying to write a PhD thesis in TexStudio backended with `biber` & `biblatex`. I've been using JabRef to handle the `bib` file until several days ago. However decided to switch to Mendeley, but parsing a lot of PDFs often with hopeless metadata entries (as Mendeley struggled to cross reference them online) seems to have created some non-UTF8 encoded strings in my new `bib` file and now upon passing through `biber` during TexStudio build I am getting the following error:

```
INFO - This is Biber 2.15 (beta)
INFO - Logfile is 'Thesis.blg'
INFO - Reading 'Thesis.bcf'
INFO - Found 26 citekeys in bib section 0
INFO - Processing section 0
INFO - Looking for bibtex format file 'Bib/Mendeley/libraryjab.bib' for section 0
ERROR - Data file 'Bib/Mendeley/libraryjab.bib' cannot be read in encoding 'utf8': Wide character at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\par-776f6c6665\cache-b32225defac3568d1e921af5a7245ca571b236aa\inc\lib/Win32/Unicode/File.pm line 163.

INFO - ERRORS: 1
```

I have checked the file, it is almost definitely UTF8 encoded itself (exported file has a comment line at the top confirming it), I tried saving it again as suggested [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/459821/biber-2-11-data-file-cannot-be-read-in-encoding-utf-8-ill-formed-utf-8), which hasn't helped.
I checked the preamble and the

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage
    [backend=biber,
    bibencoding=utf8]{biblatex}
```

are definitely there.

I ran the JabRef entry clean-up tool to convert all text fields to Unicode. No dice.
I even tried to use the older version of the `bib` file pre-dating switch to Mendeley - which DOES work fine with my `.tex` file, so the problem is most certainly with one/some of the new entries.

I also tried removing all of the files generated by the Build and Building again. Same problems persist.
I have tried to manually prune whatever erroneous entries I could find, but I continue to get the error.

Is there a way I could to find and remove the wide characters causing the problem in my `.bib` file?
There are hundreds of references so I'd rather avoid continuing to investigate them manually.

Comment: that is a bug in biber, it has problems with too long bib-files. Try the development version, see https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/332

Comment: `cat input.bib | iconv -f utf-8 -t latin1 -c | iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 > output.bib` maybe?

Comment: Going by what @UlrikeFischer says, can anyone advise if switching to LF encoding would potentially cause issues? I'm not sure splitting the `bib` file into smaller chunks that biber can cope with makes any sense for a lengthy bibliography that I'll end up having.

Comment: why don't you simply install biber 2.16dev? you only need to put the binary in your path https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/development/binaries/Windows/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't know what exactly happens, I only know that it broke if the file exceeded a certain length, the content didn't matter (it broke also if it was ascii).

Comment: what is LF encoding?

Comment: Forgive me being a noob with these things - how do I install biber from a zipped executible? It seems to do nothing when I launch it straight from a download folder and I usually downloaded these via the MikTeX console.
@UlrikeFischer

Comment: you only need to unzip the zip, it contains a biber.exe. You can either replace your existing biber.exe with it, but you can also leave it in the folder and call it as C:\path\to\the\folder\biber, or you can rename it to eg. biber-dev.exe and put somewhere where it is found and then call biber-dev.exe instead.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, @UlrikeFischer's solution for this biber bug has worked! Bibliography has loaded without issues. Looks like it's indeed an issue with `.bib` file length.
For anyone experiencing this in the future, replace the biber 2.15 with 2.16.

Many thanks folks!

Comment: And see the other topic https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/562607/206959 for the details.
This seems to be an issue Win only bug.